# What is the maximum number of indexes per table for SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, indexing, max, windows-xp

What is the maximum number of indexes per table for SQLite? (on Windows XP if that changes anything!)

Comment: It's questions like this that make me think that, regardless of the answer, the underlying reason you're asking needs to be reconsidered.

Comment: Don't worry!  :)  I was not about to create 128 indexes on the same table!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found this when I searched "sqlite indexes". I use Google; it's a pretty good search engine.

> [There are no arbitrary limits](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) on the number of indices that can be
>   attached to a single table. The number of columns in an index is
>   limited to the value set by sqlite3_limit(SQLITE_LIMIT_COLUMN,...).

Comment: Yep, I knew about this Google thing... lol ;)  I guess my search was way too precise to find any useful link!  But thanks again!